# How do I compose a code to find the estimate I am having a really hard time with this?

Tags: python

```
 "Travel Time Calculator"
  Enter miles: 200
  Enter miles per hour: 65
 "Estimated travel time"
  Hours: 3
  Minutes: 5
```

my code so far

```
    print("Time Traveling Calculator")
    
    miles = int(input("Enter miles:"))
    milesperhours = int(input("Enter miles per hour:"))
    
    import math
    
    print("Estimated Time Travel")
    print(miles/milesperhours)
    hours = int("hours:")
```

I need help with finding the estimate.

Comment: what exactly do you need help with? the travel time is already calculated in your code. also `hours = int("hours:")` is gonna give you an error, that line is asking python to turn the string "hours:" into an integer, which it cant do

Comment: What is `int("hours:")` meant to do?

Comment: You can see by following the example you already have that you need `hours = int(input("hours:"))`, right?

Comment: @TimRoberts (My guess is not. I think the last half is the required output of the program)

Comment: I think you want to print `"hours:"`, not convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to convert the string `Hours:` to an integer. You want to extract the integer hours part of the total time, and use `Hours:` as part of the output string with that. Similarly, you want to calculate the minutes remainder and print that after `Minutes:`.

```
    print("Estimated Time Travel")
    total_minutes = math.round(miles/milesperhours * 60)
    print(f'Hours: {total_minutes//60}')
    print(f'Minutes: {total_minutes % 60}')
```